# why input fields keep reading previously written inputs?

Tags: html, forms

If i write something into an input field, then refresh the page without submission, the input keeps showing those written text. is this browser issue or can be disabled with code, like js or jQuery.
I am not speaking about autocomplete i need to refresh the page and get correct inputs in place.

Comment: Its your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Your brower caches the input you submit so if you lose connection or unintentionally close the page you don't lose the data you already typed.

You can obviously override this (why?) by adding a bit of javascript to manually empty those fields. Below an example with jQuery :

```js
$(function(){
 $('#inputId').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputId" value="Hello, there...">
```